Watermelon huge disease
Leaves started yellowing then die completly. Some vines died completly. Should I worry? I afraid they will die before fruits ripe.
Charleston Gray:



Edit: they look like to be mostly dead now:


I can't really see anything wrong here... Cucurbits, like pumpkins, cucumbers and watermelons tend to experience a dieback of of the oldest growth and a general weakening of the vines when they are nearing the end of their lifespan and fruiting season. I wouldn't worry, you should still get your watermelon crop.

But some fruits are still small. I don't feel that's the end of life span. Now, almost all of them are dead

Question updated - do you think that's normal or some kind of disease?

No, this is normal, the vines naturally start dying off as the fruit fully ripen; and to your comment about some fruit still being small, it actually looks like you planted two different varieties without realising it; try picking some, cutting them open and trying them: you should have an answer to your ripeness question fairly quickly.

Yes, 2 different varietes planted. But both died with some small fruits and even with flowers. Some fruits have reached their final size, I tried one of them and it seems to bo not fully ripe. For now, I'm still waiting until they completly die, but I don't know if makes any sense
